# How to imitate rotation from the photos app on thumbnail view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an app that mimics the photos app in that it displays a table of thumbnails which represent an album that the user has clicked on. I'm having trouble imitating the animation of this window when rotation is occurred. For your reference the window I'm talking about is below:

[image]
[image]

I'm able to get the end result to turn out fine (ie after the animation is complete, everything works), however my rotation doesn't look as good as the photos app. The photos app actually looks like it's rotating the window and you can barely notice the photos resetting themselves. On mine, you can see the thumbnails sort of moving around  and it doesn't look as good.

Does anyone have a clue as to what the photos app is doing? Is it possible that it's speeding up the animation, or maybe blurring it in the middle so you can't see what's going on? My code is listed below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        for (UIButton *photoButton in [cell subviews])
        {
            [photoButton removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    NSInteger photosPerRow;

    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        photosPerRow = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        photosPerRow = 6;
    }

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(4, 2, 75, 75);

    for (int i = [indexPath row] * photosPerRow; i < (([indexPath row] * photosPerRow) + photosPerRow) && i < [[self photos] count]; i++)
    {
        [[photos objectAtIndex:i] setFrame:frame];
        [cell addSubview: [photos objectAtIndex:i]];
        frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + frame.size.width + 4;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Then here is how I'm animating it in my tableview controller:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

UPDATE: Well, I've tried a lot. So far switched all my code to a scroll view, then tried to have the thumbnails animated as follows when a rotation occurs: fade out the thumbnail, move it to it's new location, then fade it in. Of course I only did that with UIThumbViews that needed to be moved. I coming to the conclusion that apple must be using two views in order to pull them off. One view with the old set of thumbnail views, then rotating over the new set of thumbnail views. Any ideas?

Comment: I can guarantee to you that the photos app won't be using a `UITableView`. I would do this with a `UIScrollView` and then when you rotate you move the frames of the individual images around and it then should all look smooth.

Comment: I agree with mattjgalloway. If I were you, I would subclass UIScrollView, and create a method to take numberOfThumbnailPerRow and index of a row as inputs, and return an array of NSValue with CGPoints for the origin of each square (Thumbnails).

Comment: You absolutely don't use a UIScrollView, you use a UITableView, so it will only load the thumbnails that appear on the screen, and dequeue cells that have already been used. No point in implementing all this functionality when apple does it for you. And oh yeah, the rotation can be done in two lines if you implement it with a tableview as opposed to a scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: This takes two lines of code, and you have to implement the thumbnails view in a `tableview`, not a `scrollView`:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```